# Aplicação embarcada com Javascript e AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

tudo bom? Estou precisando de uma luz. Vou descrever um breve cenário:

Imaginem uma aplicação em FLASH (para exibição de vídeos, streaming, mídias dinamicas, etc..) e C (controle de memória, servidor http interno para comunicação entre flash e C, gerenciamento de storage, etc..) rodando em cima de um hardware bem limitado. Funciona? Sim, é o que temos até o momento e está indo muito bem, porém, o FLASH está "acabado" e bem limitado, além de um consumo absurdo de memória.

Minha ideia é: Migrar do FLASH para HTML5 e JS. Porém, não sou muito conhecedor dessas tecnologias e estou com algumas duvidas, que são elas:

• Javascript é uma linguagem que não possui tipagem forte, assim como flash, logo, o consumo de memória (qualquer pouco consume dentro de um hardware com pouca memória é muito) se torna equivalente ou menor que o FLASH (isso baseado em forma geral, e não como o código está programado) ?

• Javascript não é multithread, mas, vi que existe umas bibliotecas que conseguem "fazer isso". O que é o mais recomendado nessa situação? Basicamente preciso fazer uma maquina de estados, porém, queria conseguir separar as tarefas em threads diferentes.

• AngularJS: Estou pensando em usar esse framework devido ao fato que é possível implementar testes, é um framework MVC (hoje o código que roda está muito estruturado), chamadas fáceis a servidores HTTP, e também pelo fato de não depender da nossa biblioteca em C (acho que da pra mokar muita coisa né pra desenvolvimento né?). Este é o melhor pra esse tipo de situação que descrevi (tem o detalhe também do databind que será um pouco útil, pois a aplicação tem umas 6 telas de configuração e tal)?

• HTML5: É recomendado para vídeos streaming? Ele tem suporte nativo a isso ou é necessário usar bibliotecas de terceiros?

Bom, era isso. Um grande abraço a todos!

Comment: Muitas perguntas numa só :) Quanto a rodar a aplicação embarcada, pode ser uma boa ideia, sugiro ver o [Web2Executable](https://github.com/jyapayne/Web2Executable) para gerar um executável do site (ao invés de abrir um navegador tradicional em tela cheia por exemplo).

Comment: Interessante notar que a tipagem fraca não tem nada a ver com um alto consumo de memória. C é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca, por exemplo. Além disso, a tipagem fraca de Javascript pode ser resolvida usando TypeScript (é parecido com os type guards do strict mode do ActionScript 3)